# rtweet: how to get the followers count of followers of a user?

Tags: r, rtweet

The following solution: [Getting followers of multiple Twitter Users via rtweet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222757/getting-followers-of-multiple-twitter-users-via-rtweet)

provides just a tibble with the id of followers.
I'd like the count of followers for each ID.

[List of followers example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4x0o.png)

In this case I have a list consisting of thousands followers, coming from a

```
get_followers(name)
```

I'd like a new column that counts the followers of each ID, so each element of the first column

For example this site: https://followerwonk.com/analyze

allows to get a breakdown of followers count by follower of a specific user

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Let me know if it results clearer now

Answer (score 1):

Solution found using a different library (library(twitteR)): https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/06/characterizing-twitter-followers-with-tidytext/

```
followers_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = log2(followersCount))) +
    geom_density(color = palette_light()[1], fill = palette_light()[1], alpha = 0.8) +
    theme_tq() +
    labs(x = "log2 of number of followers",
         y = "density")
```